# svnserve authentication fails after adding new user

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have an Ubuntu 23.04 box that has had svnserve running for close to 15 years. Today I edited the passwd file to add another user and now I get

`Unable to connect to a repository at URL. Authentication failed`

I'm using Tortoise SVN for Windows as my client. I went into the settings and cleared all the authentication data but I still get the same result.

Can anyone suggest a fix?

Expected to add a new user/pass to passwd file and have it function as always. If I edit the new username and password out the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

NVM.

I had another repository on the server with the same login credentials. I copied that passwd file over to the problem repository and added the new user. Works just fine now